# How to show data points on top of matplotlib imshow contour plot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, contour, imshow

I have made a contour plot using `imshow`. The value of `z` is calculated for a range of `x` and `y` values as can be seen from the code below. As a next step I want to plot some calculated `z_new` values for some random `x_new` and `y_new` on top of the contour image which may be marked by closed circles or something similar.

The code reads as:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors

x = np.linspace(-0.5, 2.0, 101)
y = np.linspace(-0.5, 2.0, 101)
z = np.zeros((101, 101))
E = 0.0
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        z[i,j] = -max(y[j]+0.2+E, 0.5-x[i], 0)
        
x_new = np.array([1.1168189, 0.8381589, 1.3312789, -0.2149011])
y_new = np.array([1.7571379, 1.5555579, 1.9138179, 0.7912879])
z_new = []
for k, l in zip(x_new, y_new):
    #print (k, l, -max(l+0.2+E, 0.5-k, 0)) # z_new = -max(l+0.2+eU, 0.5-k, 0) calculated for some random x_new and y_new
    z_new.append(-max(l+0.2+E, 0.5-k, 0)) # I would like to see these z_new points on the contour plot for corresponding x_new and y_new

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ms = plt.imshow(z.T, cmap='plasma', vmin=-2.5, vmax=0, origin='lower', interpolation='none', extent=[-0.5,2.0,-0.5,2.0])
ax.set_xlabel('x', fontsize=16, fontname = "Helvetica")
ax.set_ylabel('y', fontsize=16, fontname = "Helvetica")
cbar = plt.colorbar(ms)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=10, direction='out')
cbar.set_label('z', fontsize=16, fontname = "Helvetica")
#plt.savefig('test.pdf')
plt.xticks(fontname = "Helvetica", fontsize=12)
plt.yticks(fontname = "Helvetica", fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a scatter top on top of your heat map with the last line of the code below. The circles are hard to see without the edges, though when you spot them you can get a good feel for how their values compare to the heat map. You can add black edges to the circles by uncommenting the line above the `plt.scatter` command, which makes the circles easy to locate but the differences in color hard to see.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors

x = np.linspace(-0.5, 2.0, 101)
y = np.linspace(-0.5, 2.0, 101)
z = np.zeros((101, 101))
E = 0.0
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        z[i,j] = -max(y[j]+0.2+E, 0.5-x[i], 0)
        
x_new = np.array([1.1168189, 0.8381589, 1.3312789, -0.2149011])
y_new = np.array([1.7571379, 1.5555579, 1.9138179, 0.7912879])
z_new = []
for k, l in zip(x_new, y_new):
    #print (k, l, -max(l+0.2+E, 0.5-k, 0)) # z_new = -max(l+0.2+eU, 0.5-k, 0) calculated for some random x_new and y_new
    z_new.append(-max(l+0.2+E, 0.5-k, 0)) # I would like to see these z_new points on the contour plot for corresponding x_new and y_new

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ms = plt.imshow(z.T, cmap='plasma', vmin=-2.5, vmax=0, origin='lower', interpolation='none', extent=[-0.5,2.0,-0.5,2.0])
ax.set_xlabel('x', fontsize=16, fontname = "Helvetica")
ax.set_ylabel('y', fontsize=16, fontname = "Helvetica")
cbar = plt.colorbar(ms)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=10, direction='out')
cbar.set_label('z', fontsize=16, fontname = "Helvetica")
#plt.savefig('test.pdf')
plt.xticks(fontname = "Helvetica", fontsize=12)
plt.yticks(fontname = "Helvetica", fontsize=12)

## New code ##
# plt.scatter(x_new, y_new, c=z_new, cmap='plasma', vmin=-2.5, vmax=0, edgecolors='black') # Uncomment this if you want the points circled in black
plt.scatter(x_new, y_new, c='green') # Uncomment if you want green circles
# plt.scatter(x_new, y_new, c=z_new, cmap='plasma', vmin=-2.5, vmax=0)
## End of new code ##

plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I was exactly looking for. May I ask a couple of short queries please? How about I want to see those new points with a filled color? I know that they are following the map color and which makes them hard to distinguish. So, let's forget about the color-coding of the new points and please let me know how can I fill those circles with any other color say yellow? The second query is how to change the font style of the ticks of the color bar from default to say, Helvetica? I was able to change the font of the heat map but couldn't do it for the color bar. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.
Circle points: see update in the end of code.
Tick font: I can't put code in here but if you create a new question I'll answer it. It's simple.